# Changing the background color more brighter if it is active using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i am having the list of categories in my website as of now the one which is not active its opacity will be less and the one which selected that text will be dark.If i give the opacity for not selected list i am unable to see the text which is present and all.
So i just need to remove the opacity for the not selected one and should add more brightness to the selected one.
There are different colors for the list of items.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#tribe-events #legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if it is about brightness(), take a look at CSS filter https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter . Your snippet is missing the container `#tribe-events` . It doesn't help showing your issue as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead opacity, you can give a try to the filter css brightness().

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
>
> The `filter` CSS property lets you apply graphical effects like blurring or color shifting to an element. Filters are commonly used to adjust the rendering of images, backgrounds, and borders.

```css
/* demo using the tabindex attribute to catch focus event on li*/
li:focus {filter:brightness(200%)}


/* demo makup */
ul {counter-reset:li}
li:before {  counter-increment:li; content:'This item number 'counter(li);}
li {background:gray;color:purple}
li:nth-child(3n) {background:green;color:tomato}
li:nth-child(2n-2) {background:turquoise;color:crimson}
```

```html
<ul><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li></ul>
```

or the  a mix of increasing and decreasing `brightness()`

```css
/* demo using the tabindex attribute to catch focus event on li*/

li:not(:focus) {filter:brightness(50%)}
li:focus {filter:brightness(150%)}


/* demo makup */
ul {counter-reset:li}
li:before {  counter-increment:li; content:'This item number 'counter(li);}
li {background:gray;color:purple}
li:nth-child(3n) {background:green;color:tomato}
li:nth-child(2n-2) {background:turquoise;color:crimson}
```

```html
<ul><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li><li tabindex="0"></li></ul>
```

> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/
>
> CSS Filters are a powerful tool that authors can use to achieve varying visual effects (sort of like Photoshop filters for the browser). The CSS filter property provides access to effects like blur or color shifting on an element’s rendering before the element is displayed. Filters are commonly used to adjust the rendering of an image, a background, or a border.
>
> The syntax is:
>
> ```
> .filter-me {
>   filter: <filter-function> [<filter-function>]* | none
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Change CSS code like below:-

```
#legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

See working example:-

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
    jQuery("#legend li").removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.active {
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```

Note:-

`#tribe-events` is child of `legend`, so your code CSS will not work at all.

Also `#legend li` will check for all `li's` so there is no need of `#tribe-events` at-all in your CSS code.

***You can use `font-size` and `font-weight` attribute to nake selected text looks bolder and brighter***

Comment: You can use `font-size` and `font-weight` attribute to do that. Check in my edited solution

Comment: If i add font size and font weight for the active one it is not changing if i select the other list item it remains the same for the previous one as well

Comment: @user8725518  You have to do jQuery code for that. (when other one selected then remove active from previous li). Check my edited code.I have added that one also.click on different links and see

Answer (score 1):

No need to add   `#tribe-events` in css code. Remove that and try

```
   #legend li:not(.active) {
   opacity: 0.3;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your pasted code, I can understand that, you are reducing the opacity for non-active elements.

If you want to remove the opacity for non-selected item, increase the `opacity: 1;`.

**For highlighting selected items, use different `background-color` for the selected items**.

```
.active{
    background-color : //something-differ-than-non-active
}
#legend li:not(.active) {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Or adding brightness dynamically on hover,**

```
$(".active li").hover(
    function () {
        //OnHover 
        $(this).css("background-color", LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")), 20));
    }, function () {
        //AfterHover
        $(this).css("background-color", LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex($(this).css("background-color")), -20));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful for you

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").addClass("active");
  jQuery(".tribe-events-category-5").trigger("click");
  jQuery("#legend li").on("click", function() {
     jQuery(".active").removeClass("active");
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
#tribe-events #legend li:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="legend">
  <li><span>All</span></li>
  <li class="tribe-events-category-5"><span>Music</span></li>
  <li><span>Dance</span></li>
  <li><span>Festives</span></li>
</ul>
```